# Device Token for Push Notification

Tags: android, windows, blackberry, push-notification, token

I am implementing a push notification service. I would need to create a database to store all the device tokens from the 4 mobile platforms. I want to organize them accordingly to their platforms(iOS,Android,BlackBerry,WP7). But what are the ways to differentiate the platforms so that if I want to send a message to only Android users, the other platforms will not receive it.

I am using ManicNetwork but unfortunately, the software does not help to differentiate the platforms.

Apple is using a 64bytess hexadecimal string in their token. But how about the other 3 platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try saving the tokens in different tables. For example, Apple in one, Android in the other.

Or like what marimaf said, add another attribute to be sent to the server. For example,

`Apple -  App`

`Android - And`

`BlackBerry - BB`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another attribute when you register the device id on your server that indicates the devices OS. Then you can filter by this attribute and get the OS you want.